# Prime divisor of $2^{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While working on a question on Abstract algebra, my working arrives at

> $p \mid 2^{n}$

where $ p \in \mathbb{P} $and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can I deduce that p indeed is 2?

Comment: Apply the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic is great, but induction using the definition works here too. Since $p \mid 2^n$, either $p \mid 2$ (in which case things are clear), or $p \mid 2^{n-1}$. Now just induct down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a prime $p$ divides $2^n$ then $p$ is $2$.

Proof:

We proceed by induction on $n$, when $n=1$ the claim is , if $p|2$ then $p=2$, this is clear since only $1$ and $2$ divide $p$. (we can do this more carefully if required).

Inductive step:

Suppose $p|2^{n+1}=2^n\times 2$, by Euclid's lemma we conclude $p|2$ or $p|2^n$, if $p|2$ then $p=2$ and if $p|2^n$ then $p=2$ by the inductive hyppthesis.

Comment: I really like this. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it helped, although I myself am not really a big fan of rigour :)

Comment: @Mathematicing Actually you can do this inductive argument more elementarily using just arithmetic instead of Euclid's Lemma - see my answer. But Euclid's Lemma is the way to go in general.

Answer (score 3):

Use Euclid's lemma:

$p\mid 2(2^{n-1})$ so $p\mid 2$ or $p\mid 2^{n-1}$.

If $p\mid 2$ you are done, otherwise continue the process inductively which will terminate since $n$ is finite.

Answer (score 3):

Note $\ ak\!+\!1\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,ak\!+\!1\mid b = (ak\!+\!1)b-k(ab)$

Thus  $\ 2k\!+\!1\mid 2b\,\Rightarrow\,2k\!+\!1\mid b,\,\ $ so $\,\ 2k\!+\!1\mid 2^nb\,\Rightarrow\,2k\!+\!1\mid b,\ $ by induction

Comment: That's a direct argument *that generalizes* (in case you don't yet have available gcds / Bezout, Euclid's Lemma, or the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic or other high power tools).

Comment: +1, your answers are usually different from what I would do.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling This is really just a special case of the standard Bezout based argument that if $\, (c,a) = 1\,$ then $\, c\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid b.\,$ Above the Bezout identity is obvious, viz. $\, (ak\!+\!1) - k(a) = 1.\ $ Scaling that by $\,b\,$ gives the proof in my answer, just like in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: All primes besides $2$ are odd.

Thus no other prime can divide $2^n$. If $p \neq 2$ existed such that $p | 2^n$, then $2^n = p * k$, clearly a contradiction by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I was just aiming to show that since by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic the prime factorization contains only $2$, we can't have any other prime as a divisor.